# How to make Ecto.changeset validate_required accept blank values?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, changeset

What I'm trying to do is passing an empty string as the value of a field, and validating it to check if not nil. Problem is that validate_required raise error on both nil and blank values. How to make it accept blank values?

schema

```
  schema "messages" do
    field :user_id, :string
    field :text, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

changeset

```
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:text, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:text, :user_id])
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The behavior of `validate_required` is unfortunately [hardcoded](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/ea543af75832b755e16f62015f6ae6cec00fc033/lib/ecto/changeset.ex#L1487) to consider empty as well as whitespace only strings as missing. You can however write a simple function to do the validation:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:text, :user_id])
  |> validate_not_nil([:text, :user_id])
end

def validate_not_nil(changeset, fields) do
  Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
    if get_field(changeset, field) == nil do
      add_error(changeset, field, "nil")
    else
      changeset
    end
  end)
end
```

The function goes over each field, adding error for every field which has a value `nil`.

Comment: This only works if you also declare a default value on the field: `field :my_field, :string, default: ""`

See also the [docs on empty values in changesets](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-empty-values).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1684

Even if that won't fix your problem, adding a default value to the definition will allow you to create a *workaround* that will completely avoid the null value, even if it is not what you intend.